# How do I create a reactive dependency on a reactive object field which may not exist yet?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-tracker

Given an object full of good reactivity,

```
var obj = {
  foo : new ReactiveVar(0),
  bar : new ReactiveVar(0)
};
```

I can easily react to these fields with a Tracker computation:

```
Tracker.autorun(function logObj() {
  console.log('obj.foo is:', obj.foo.get());
  console.log('obj.bar is:', obj.bar.get());
});
```

However, if I know that at a later date `obj.baz` is going to be defined and I also want to react to it ***as soon as it is defined*** I can't do that:

```
Tracker.autorun(function logObj() {
  console.log('obj.foo is:', obj.foo.get());
  console.log('obj.bar is:', obj.bar.get());
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty('baz')) console.log('obj.baz is:', obj.baz.get());
});
```

This happens because if it runs without `obj.baz` being defined then it won't add a dependency over it and thus won't rerun if it appears or changes. The only way `obj.baz` will be reacted unto is if `foo` or `bar` invalidate the computaton while `baz` is defined, thus calling the `.get()` and creating the dependency.

How can I react to the creation of a yet non-defined object field? I would prefer the answer being in ES5, but I am okay with ES6 or ES7.

Comment: We ran into the same issue when creating components - the only solution we found was to create a wrapper that defines the reactive state whenever it's read for the first time. This seems to conflict with the last paragraph of your question so I'm uncertain if it's an acceptable answer.

Comment: Couldn't you create a shadow reactive variable which contains the type of *baz* and react to that changing from undefined to some other type?

Comment: What's wrong with using `ReactiveDict`?

Comment: Thinking about this further, why not make the whole object a reactive var instead of the keys within it. Then you can react to any change to the entire object instead of just the keys. It's actually javascript that's stopping you from being reactive to *obj.baz` since you can't attach the reactive functions (*dep* and *equalsFunc*) to a key that doesn't exist yet. Finally, couldn't you also just initialize *obj.baz* in when you create *obj* (if it doesn't exist yet) and let it change when defined elsewhere?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Ah, there is a reason to that although it's not in the question. I may want to have dependencies on a subset of the fields, not on all of them at once. For example, observing only `foo`, or only `bar` and a non-existing `name`...

Comment: If you are only going to store numbers and strings then the performance impact is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @apendua Unfortunately, I am not, and I have already measured the performance impact to be too great for my goal.